# Use one dependency in Node, another in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, browserify

I'm working on an NPM module that will wrap around a rather ancient "RESTful-like" [web API](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25500/) to retrieve data. Some of the data from this API is only available as XML. I've been using [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) to transform it parse it.

I'd ideally like a package that can work in either Node or the browser. I recently added a browserify build task and the output file was 416kb. Seems a little big for what it is. Turns out half the bulk is coming from xml2js.

It seems like having access to the browser's DOM parser should make parsing XML pretty simple. Basically I'd like to override my `require('xml2js')` statement when using browserify with either a custom script or a different package.

I found [`browserify-bypass`](https://github.com/jhnns/browserify-bypass) but it doesn't seem to work anymore ... I get `browserify(...).use` is not a function, which is fair enough - it hasn't been updated in four years.

Is there some way to do this that I'm missing, if not with browserify than with Webpack?

Comment: Maybe [aliasify](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify) would help.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. If you want to submit it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [aliasify](https://github.com/benbria/aliasify) You can define aliases for modules in `packgage.json`:

```
{
    "aliasify": {
        "aliases": {
            "underscore": "lodash"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, `require('underscore')` will be automatically transformed to `require('lodash')`.